# Login of some accounts takes forever

Tags: nginx, voip

I have used ASTPP for some years now, recently I received a report from some customers who can't log in. I looked into it and discovered that some accounts of the system logs in usually, a few seconds and you're in, but other accounts take minutes to log in and others receive a 504 timeout error and are never or almost never able to log in.

I've checked the browser console and Nginx error log and these are the only messages left:

`2023/06/26 19:10:32 [error] 1919#0: *19 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: CLI.ENT.IP.ADD, server: my.domain, request: "GET /user/user/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "my.domain", referrer: "https://my.domain/"`
`GET https://my.domain/user/user/ 504 (Gateway Time-out)`

I've compared differences among the accounts that can log in and the accounts with the issue but I haven't found any difference with these accounts that may be causing the delay. No more logs or error messages are available. No MySQL errors or similar. Tried different browsers with the same behavior. I don't know how to extract more debug from the system or diagnose what's the cause of the problem.

Any advice is highly appreciated.